# Swift: Making call not always work in specific scenarios

Tags: ios, swift, url

In my controller I have 2 buttons, a button to send an sms, and a button to make a call.

The problem is that making a call doesn't always work.

To reproduce this:

- I click on the sms button
- I exit the sms application to return to my application
- I click on the call button and it does NOT work
- I click on the sms button
- I exit the sms application to return to my application
- I click on the call button and IT WORKS

It also works if:

- As soon as I enter my controller for the first time I click on the call button.
- But as soon as I click on the sms button cel reproduce the flow described above.

Here is my code:

```
    func makeCall() {
        openExternalUrl(string: "telprompt://\(phone)")
    }

    func makeSMS() {
        openExternalUrl(string: "sms:\(phone)")
    }

    func openExternalUrl(string: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: string), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
```

I tried `telprompt://\(phone)` and `tel://\(phone)` and get same result.

When I print the completion of `open(url:,completion:)` the boolean returned is always true even when the popup of the call is not displayed

Comment: Make sure you invoke your methods on main thread, maybe can help

Comment: Real device and sim

Comment: I call it from main thread and not work

Comment: Use `"tel:\(phone)"`

Comment: @Paulw11 Get same result...

Comment: You shouldn't use `canOpenURL` for tel and sms URLs. It will always return true. Also, rather than opening an sms URL I suggest you use MFMessageComposeViewController to avoid bouncing the user out of your app.